# VS regex srch/repl - how to ignore lines with phrases?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, visual-studio-2015

I know this has been asked before, but when I search, I am buried with tons of answers that don't help.

I am converting code from an old language into C# using visual studio.  I can use Regex for much of what I need to do.

The old language did not use statement terminators.  So I need to add one to every line that DOESNT start with //, foreach, if, switch, case, etc. ( and is not blank).

This is the only step remaining before I next go through and fix all the code that the generic search/replace couldn't handle.

Anyway, given the VS regex search/replace option, what syntax would you recommend to essentially select every line that doesn't have those keywords and replace the \r\n with ;\r\n?

All I need is a link to an answer that fixes this, but as I said, so far, I have found a bunch of answers that almost, but not quite do this.

While I am comfortable with basic Regex, I still struggle with some of the cool capabilities (look ahead/behind, etc.)  So if the answer requires such an approach, would also appreciate a brief explanation of why that is used.

So far, I have been trying options based on using the ^ - such at [^(if|foreach|xxx)] but that isn't selecting the lines that don't have those (at least not properly.)

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *So I need to add one to every line that DOESNT start with //, foreach, if, switch, case, etc.* - `^(?!\s*(?://|(?:foreach|if|switch|case)\b)).+`

Comment: That works great for everything except blank lines (and braces, but I figured those out.) Any idea on how to also ignore blank lines?

Comment: Blank lines can be added - `^(?!\s*(?://|(?:foreach|if|switch|case)\b)|$).+`. If it works, I will post.

Comment: That seems to do it.  I did have to change it as follows: (^(?!\s*(?://|{|}|(?:break|foreach|if|switch|case)\b)|$))(.+). so that it would allow me to do the replace (using $2 ; ).

Answer (score 1):

In VS S&R, you may use the following:

- Match the start of a line with `^`
- Match 0+ whitespaces with `\s*` (note it won't match linebreaks in VS)
- Match one of the alternatives after these optional whitespaces: `//` - literal double slashes, `(?:foreach|if|switch|case)\b` - whole words `foreach`, `if`, `swtich` and `case`
- Check the end of line with `$`
- Match any 1+ chars on a line with `.+`.
- Make sure the line does not start with those patterns with a *negative lookahead* `(?!...)` anchored at the start (i.e. right after `^`).

Combining them into 1 expression:

```
^(?!\s*(?://|(?:foreach|if|switch|case)\b)|$).+
```

To add `{` and `}`, you may use a character class `[{}]` and add it as an alternative:

```
^(?!\s*(?://|[{}]|(?:break|foreach|if|switch|case)\b)|$)(.+‌​)
```

Note I removed the grouping around the lookahead as it always contains NO TEXT since a lookahead is a zero-width assertion that does not return text into the match. So, you onky have 1 group and access it via `$1` if you need to replace the line with something else.